# Transform R data.table from four id columns to one id column by creating additional columns

Tags: r, machine-learning, data.table, feature-extraction

I am attempting to create ~1000 features for a machine learning problem using data.table.  I have two tables that are linked by an id.  The first table has a unique id per row, we'll call x.  The second table has multiple rows for every id, x.  In addition I have three other columns that are factor type variables.  I also have a bunch of other numeric columns that I need to use. My goal is to  calculate the min, max, mean for each numeric variable grouped by x and the other factor variables then reshape the information such that there is only one unique x id per row by creating a column for each combination of the factor columns along with the associated calculated numeric column.  Since I have many numeric columns, I would also like to do this without having to hard code the columns and without a loop, since there are many numeric columns.

As an example I can create a data.table in the basic structure with:

```
set.seed(1234)
DT <- data.table(x=rep(c(1,2,3),each=8), 
        y1=c("A","B"), y2=c("C","D", "E"),y3=c("F","G"), v1=sample(1:100,12),
        v2=sample(1:100,12), v3=sample(1:100,12))
DT
    x y1 y2 y3 v1  v2 v3
 1: 1  A  C  F 12  29 22
 2: 1  B  D  G 62  92 81
 3: 1  A  E  F 60 100 52
 4: 1  B  C  G 61  82 89
 5: 1  A  D  F 83  28 80
 6: 1  B  E  G 97  26  5
 7: 1  A  C  F  1  18 43
 8: 1  B  D  G 22  22 25
 9: 2  A  E  F 99  30 29
10: 2  B  C  G 47  96 47
11: 2  A  D  F 63  15 17
12: 2  B  E  G 49   4 68
13: 2  A  C  F 12  29 22
14: 2  B  D  G 62  92 81
15: 2  A  E  F 60 100 52
16: 2  B  C  G 61  82 89
17: 3  A  D  F 83  28 80
18: 3  B  E  G 97  26  5
19: 3  A  C  F  1  18 43
20: 3  B  D  G 22  22 25
21: 3  A  E  F 99  30 29
22: 3  B  C  G 47  96 47
23: 3  A  D  F 63  15 17
24: 3  B  E  G 49   4 68
    x y1 y2 y3 v1  v2 v3
```

And then create an example grouping using:

```
interim <- DT[,list(v1min=min(v1),
                v1max=max(v1),
                v1mean=mean(v1),
                v2min=min(v2),
                v2max=max(v2),
                v2mean=mean(v2),
                v3min=min(v3),
                v3max=max(v3),
                v3mean=mean(v3)),
                by=.(x,y1,y2,y3)]
interim

    x y1 y2 y3 v1min v1max v1mean v2min v2max v2mean v3min v3max v3mean
 1: 1  A  C  F     1    12    6.5    18    29   23.5    22    43   32.5
 2: 1  B  D  G    22    62   42.0    22    92   57.0    25    81   53.0
 3: 1  A  E  F    60    60   60.0   100   100  100.0    52    52   52.0
 4: 1  B  C  G    61    61   61.0    82    82   82.0    89    89   89.0
 5: 1  A  D  F    83    83   83.0    28    28   28.0    80    80   80.0
 6: 1  B  E  G    97    97   97.0    26    26   26.0     5     5    5.0
 7: 2  A  E  F    60    99   79.5    30   100   65.0    29    52   40.5
 8: 2  B  C  G    47    61   54.0    82    96   89.0    47    89   68.0
 9: 2  A  D  F    63    63   63.0    15    15   15.0    17    17   17.0
10: 2  B  E  G    49    49   49.0     4     4    4.0    68    68   68.0
11: 2  A  C  F    12    12   12.0    29    29   29.0    22    22   22.0
12: 2  B  D  G    62    62   62.0    92    92   92.0    81    81   81.0
13: 3  A  D  F    63    83   73.0    15    28   21.5    17    80   48.5
14: 3  B  E  G    49    97   73.0     4    26   15.0     5    68   36.5
15: 3  A  C  F     1     1    1.0    18    18   18.0    43    43   43.0
16: 3  B  D  G    22    22   22.0    22    22   22.0    25    25   25.0
17: 3  A  E  F    99    99   99.0    30    30   30.0    29    29   29.0
18: 3  B  C  G    47    47   47.0    96    96   96.0    47    47   47.0
```

The ideal output would then only have 3 rows - one for each unique x (1,2,3) with the following columns (some NA's are expected):

```
x | A-C-F-v1min | A-C-F-v1max | A-C-F-v1mean | . . . | B-C-G-v3min | B-C-G-v3max | B-C-G-v3mean
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
dcast(interim, x~y1+y2+y3, value.var = setdiff(names(interim), c('x', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3')))
```

I can't remember if multiple `value.var`'s was present in 1.9.6, so you might need to get the latest [development version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I needed.  Thanks.